# String pattern wit ha dollar present

Tags: java

I have the below data in a text file.

```
CS@@NEWSLTR$$                                                                   
RY@@GLMALAW$$                                                                   
VW@@NWL$$                                                                       
VW@@GLS$$                                                                       
IS@@4$$                                                                         
ST@@NJ$$                                                                        
ST@@NY$$                                                                        
SORTX@@0050004018001$$                                                          
RC@@18 No. 4 GLMALAW 1$$                                                        
CR@@18 No. 4 M & A Law. 1$$                                                     
SO3@@The M & A Lawyer$$                                                         
DL@@April, 2014$$                                                               
TI@@DUSTING OFF APPRAISAL RIGHTS: THE DEVELOPMENT OF A NEW INVESTMENT           
 STRATEGY$$
```

here i'm actually trying to fetch these values into a java array with the below code.

```
package strings;
import com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.BasisLibrary;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 * @author u0138039
 */
public class Strings {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inFile1 = null;
        try {
            inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\u0138039\\Desktop\\Adhil\\WDA.TP.GLASSER.IB.F486806.A.D140605.T.txt")).useDelimiter("$\\\\\\\\\\\\$");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Strings.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
            tokens.add(inFile1.nextLine());
        }
        String[] tokenArray = tokens.toArray(new String[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < tokenArray.length; i++) {
            String s = tokenArray[i];
            System.out.println("a["+i+"]" +tokenArray[i]);

        }
    }
}
```

here my concept is that the line ends with a `$$` and this is how it should be stored in an array, but when i run the above program i get the below output.

```
a[0]CS@@NEWSLTR$$                                                                   
a[1]RY@@GLMALAW$$                                                                   
a[2]VW@@NWL$$                                                                       
a[3]VW@@GLS$$                                                                       
a[4]IS@@4$$                                                                         
a[5]ST@@NJ$$                                                                        
a[6]ST@@NY$$                                                                        
a[7]SORTX@@0050004018001$$                                                          
a[8]RC@@18 No. 4 GLMALAW 1$$                                                        
a[9]CR@@18 No. 4 M & A Law. 1$$                                                     
a[10]SO3@@The M & A Lawyer$$                                                         
a[11]DL@@April, 2014$$                                                               
a[12]TI@@DUSTING OFF APPRAISAL RIGHTS: THE DEVELOPMENT OF A NEW INVESTMENT           
a[13] STRATEGY$$
```

here `a[12]` and `a[13]` belong to same array number(index), but here these are divided into 2.

The expected output is as below(since the end `$$` of a[12] came in a[13])

```
a[0]CS@@NEWSLTR$$                                                                   
a[1]RY@@GLMALAW$$                                                                   
a[2]VW@@NWL$$                                                                       
a[3]VW@@GLS$$                                                                       
a[4]IS@@4$$                                                                         
a[5]ST@@NJ$$                                                                        
a[6]ST@@NY$$                                                                        
a[7]SORTX@@0050004018001$$                                                          
a[8]RC@@18 No. 4 GLMALAW 1$$                                                        
a[9]CR@@18 No. 4 M & A Law. 1$$                                                     
a[10]SO3@@The M & A Lawyer$$                                                         
a[11]DL@@April, 2014$$                                                               
a[12]TI@@DUSTING OFF APPRAISAL RIGHTS: THE DEVELOPMENT OF A NEW INVESTMENT STRATEGY$$
```

please let me know where am i going wrong and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: `STRATEGY$$` is on newLine and you are using `nextLine()` what else you expect??

Comment: `tokens.add(inFile1.nextLine());` Your program does not look at `$$`, it is reading line by line (`\n\r`)

Comment: Please read about how to create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget the `useDelimiter`

```
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    int next = 0;
    while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
        String line = inFile1.nextLine();
        if( next >= tokens.size() ){
            tokens.add( line );
        } else {
            tokens.set( next, tokens.get(next) + line );
        }                 
        if( line.endsWith( "$$" ) ) next++;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @laune, This is working like a charm, I've a small doubt, is there a way that i can retain this delimiter in my array something like `a[0] xx@@xxxx$$`, Thanks

Comment: There's no code that strips "$$" from the data, so I don't know what you mean. (You don't have a `useDelimiter` call in your code, do you?)

Answer (score 0):

You're issuing a `inFile1.nextLine()` so naturally, the strings in a[12] and a[13] would be separated.

One approach I can think of is putting the content of the file in a String object, then do a split using "\$\$" .

```
String s = "Hello$$World$$Sample$$";
for(String sa: s.split("\\$\\$")) {
    System.out.println(sa);
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
World
Sample
```

But this will not include the trailing "$$" since you used it in the split. You can easily add that do the end of your string, but this is just one approach.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String partialLine = null;
    while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
        String line = inFile1.nextLine();
        if (partialLine != null) {
            line = partialLine + line;
            partialLine = null;
        }
        if (line.endsWith("$$") {
            tokens.add(line);
        } else {
            partialLine = line;
        }
    }
    if (partialLine != null) {
        // Probably empty line.
    }
```

A bit of buffering: not adding a partial line (missing $$), but keeping it in `partialLine`.

As you see even several partial lines would work.